# Inference for binary image classification

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, conv-neural-network, predict, chainer

This a classification process for blood cells. I have 2 classes: Mononuclear and Polynuclear. The training is done. X_test is the image array and y_test is the label array. I am trying to predict the label of a single input image.

I have changed the label array into dtype int and have flattened it and image array in float32 as I have done with the training image and label. Do I need to make a test dataset as I have made a train dataset using DatasetMixin? And how do I get the desired result. I am aiming for a single image prediction only.

```
y_test = y_test.astype(int)
y_test = y_test.flatten()

batch_size = 1

dataset = MyDataset(X_test, y_test)
test_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(dataset, batch_size)

img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/TEST IMAGES/MONOCYTE.jpeg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
img=np.array((img), dtype = np.float32)
img=img/255.0

x = Variable(np.asarray([X_test[0]]))
y = model(x)

prediction = y.data.argmax(axis=1)
```

After the line y = model(x) I get the error:
TypeError: **call**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

TypeError: **call**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Comment: Please write how did you instantiate `model`.

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebook. I have just finished training the model which is in the same notebook. The name of model is MyModel.

Comment: Neerajan, please add complete code for better understanding of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might have missed `labels`, which were assumed to be fed to the model during training.

Comment: Labels are y_train and y_test for training and test dataset respectively. y_train was converted to int and then flattened before putting it into dataset_train along with X_train using DatasetMixin. This dataset_train was then split into training and validation(20%) part and fed into the model using train_iter.

Comment: x = Variable(np.asarray([X_test[0]]))
... It seems you arbitrary select image part only.
If you want "good" answer, you have to propose the minimal code to reproduce.